# Canvas smoke particles not moving

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I am building a fancy easteregg for our internal application. Therefor I have an image 'riding' through the screen. To enhance fancyness I want to add smoke to the vehicle that follows the graphic.

For the smoke I implemented a modified version of this pen:
http://codepen.io/CucuIonel/pen/hFJlr

**Here's the result:** http://jsfiddle.net/vc2d08bt/4/

The important codesnippets (as I guess) can be found in the fiddle, search for:

```
setInterval(function () {
    position.x = $('#crystalship_exhaust').offset().left;
    position.y = $('#crystalship_exhaust').offset().top;
}, 100);
```

Since the pen binds the smoke to the cursors offset, I tried binding it to a span "inside" the vehicle, to follow. But the Smoke is growing in both X-directions and is not even close to follow the vehicle.

What am I doing wrong here? I am not very familiar with canvas but thankfull for any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Draw the moving truck via the canvas and not CSS. The canvas the partials use is the size of the page by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added the movement to the car with smoke going out of the exhaust. On mouse move the travels across the screen but this is easily changeable if you'd like it. I changed the emotion direction of the partials to Y instead of X so it goes backwards and moved the image of the car with the emitter.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYapqr

**Javascript**:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var w = canvas.width = 1200,
    h = canvas.height = 700;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
```

//Added a new Car Image

```
var car = new Image();
img.src = 'http://oi41.tinypic.com/4i2aso.jpg';
```

//And set it's src property

```
car.src = 'https://openmerchantaccount.com/img2/crystalship.png';
```

//Set the starting positions to -car length so it doesn't just appear on screen

```
var position = {x : -250, y : h/2};

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var particles = [];
var random = function(min, max){
  return Math.random()*(max-min)*min;
};

function Particle(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
```

//Changed the direction of the partial to go right, not up.

```
  this.velX = -2;
  this.velY = (random(1, 10)-5)/10;
  this.size = random(3, 5)/10;
  this.alpha = 1;
  this.update = function(){
    this.y += this.velY;
    this.x += this.velX;
    this.velY *= 0.99;
    if(this.alpha < 0)
      this.alpha = 0;
    c.globalAlpha = this.alpha;
    c.save();
    c.translate(this.x, this.y);
    c.scale(this.size, this.size);

    c.drawImage(img, -img.width/2, -img.height/2);
    c.restore();
    this.alpha *= 0.96;
    this.size += 0.02;//
  };
}

var draw = function(){
```

//To animate movement, on draw move the position 2px to the right

```
  position.x+=2;
  position.y;
```

//If the car reaches the end I just move it back to the start

```
  if(position.x+250>w){
    position.x=-250;
  }

  var p = new Particle(position.x, position.y);
  particles.push(p);
  while(particles.length > 500) particles.shift();

  c.globalAlpha = 1;
  c.fillStyle = '#000';
  c.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
```

//Draw the image back on screen

```
  c.drawImage(car, position.x,position.y-80,250,100);
  for(var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
  {
    particles[i].update();
  }
};

setInterval(draw, 1000/60);
```

Comment: BUT, it is still about mousemove. Is it possible to have this eased animated in movement without binded to the mouse? (Like in the CSS3-based movement example)

Comment: I am deeply in your dept!

Comment: Canvas is used the same in most languages, you should work with it, once you have an update method, it's really fun to play around with and one of the beginning steps to Game Design.

Comment: Is it possible to have this with transparent background? If we set it to 'transparent' or 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' it is warping.

Comment: This is googleable and could be asked as a different question but here you go, I changed the end of the draw method to draw a transparent rectangle every frame before updating. (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGErmq) This should work

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since we prefered bing, we could not find any useful results. Thanks again m4te!